# Extract reply addresses from all emails in an outlook folder (sent on behalf of)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I've got to send a bulk email out to a bunch of people in reply to emails they sent me. I've got all the original emails stored in a single outlook folder. I want to extract all of the reply addresses from the emails in that folder so I can send an email to all of them.

The article [Extracting Email Address from Outlook 2007 folder](http://thetechieguy.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/extracting-email-address-from-outlook-2007-folder/) shows you how to export the FROM address of these emails, however a large amount of them came from a web service that sends emails 'on behalf of' the person I'm trying to mail to. So I need the reply-to address, and the export wizard doesn't do that.

Does anyone have a tip on how to do this? This is Outlook 2007 on Exchange 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I found what I needed using the free [CodeTwo Outlook Export utility](http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/outlook-export/)

It's fairly straight forward, but I've written full instructions [on my blog](http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2011/02/general-ithow-to-export-on-behalf-of.html).

Comment: There is also a **free** [Save Addresses from Messages to Contact Folder](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSaveFolder/) tool that does exactly what you want.

Comment: This doesn't work for Outlook 2016, the "Send on behalf of" line just exports the same as the "from" line (at least for my web form). It needs to extract the "Reply-to" line from the header.

Answer (score 1):

From [Extracting Email Address from Outlook 2007 folder](http://thetechieguy.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/extracting-email-address-from-outlook-2007-folder/) :

> So you have a folder that you keep all your sales inquiries. Now from out of nowhere you are instructed to send each person an email with your company’s new catalogue.
>
> Here is what you do:
>
> - In Outlook 2007, click on File, Import and Export and the Wizard opens
>     up.
> - Select the option to Export to a File and click on Next
> - Select Microsoft Excel 97-2003 (or a CSV file) and click on Next
> - Select the folder that your sales inquiries reside in and click on Next
> - Click on Browse to select a location and then type the file name that you
>     want to export the information to and
>     then click on Next
> - Here is the important bit – click on Map Custom Fields. This will bring up
>     a list of all the available fields
>     that are available in that folder.
>     Since we are only interested in Email
>     address, click on Clear Map and then
>     from the Left side click on From:
>     (address) and drag that to the Right
>     list
> - Click on OK
> - Click on Finish
>
> Now watch the magic happen – all the
>   Email address will be exported neatly
>   into an Excel spreadsheet that you can
>   now manipulate and use as you wish !

If you do not have Excel, the CSV option will generate a text file that you can use.

Comment: I linked to that exact post in my question and said that it is not of any use as I need the reply-to address and that option does not come up in the map custom fields menu. Have you had some success getting it to show up in that menu? If so, how?

Comment: I didn't see this was the same article (will fix this later). Why do you need "reply-to" and not "From: (Address)" ? And there is also the old trick of select-all in the folder, copy, then paste all headers into Excel.

Comment: because a large amount of them came from a web service that sends emails 'on behalf of' the person I'm trying to mail to. Ie the email is from 'do-not-reply@website.com on behalf of person-i-want-to-email@email.com' I tried copying and pasting to excel but it doesn't bring across any email addresses - is there extra options other than just purely selecting all emails, copying and then pasting?

Comment: I don't understand: You added your own accepted solution. Is it not working?