# how can I extract/harvest/export all sender addresses from outlook 2003?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, extract, address-book

I'd like to build a list of all the people who email me but can't figure out a way of doing it.

Tools such as Xobni offer a list, but it is not possible to select the data from the 'analytics'.

How can I harvest this data?

EDIT:
Needs to be recursive from root inbox folder

Comment: Not a duplicate: the question asks for a solution that works recursively, but [the cited question](http://superuser.com/questions/241115/extract-reply-addressesfrom-all-emails-in-an-outlook-folder-sent-on-behalf-of) is about mail in a single folder, and the CodeTwo utility mentioned in its accepted answer only exports the contents of a single folder and not child folders.

Answer (score 0):

Export your inbox as a csv file. Just before the export happens there will be a field chooser button (sorry can't remember the name). Inside there make sure only the "to" email address is selected.

End result will be a file that you can manipulate in Excel. You'll need to remove the duplicates but that can be handy to work out who emails you the most (and least).

Comment: This doesn't work recursively, which the OP asked for. It only exports mail from the selected folder itself, not child folders.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy with **free** [OutlookFreeware.com Save One Header](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookHeadersSaveOne/) utility. It will dump all required addresses to a flat text file. In order to find required header name (for sender) run [Save All Headers](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookHeadersSaveAll/) tool (also freeware). I'm one of developers of both tools. I already posted it here, this is actually a good solution and still no good answers. Using a third-party tool is a way to go.