# Outlook 2007 - how do I capture all email addresses in a folder to make a new distribution list?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can I bulk harvest all email addresses in a folder to create a mailing list without having to open and copy/paste each email?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract reply addressesfrom all emails in an outlook folder (sent on behalf of)](http://superuser.com/questions/241115/extract-reply-addressesfrom-all-emails-in-an-outlook-folder-sent-on-behalf-of)

Comment: This is not a duplicate - he wants to create a contact group.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **free** [Save Addresses from Messages to Contact Group](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSaveGroup/) that does exactly what you want.